# outputting scores from a quiz to a .txt file

Tags: python, output, text-files

I have done this code to output scores to a .txt file but there are no errors and it still won't output the scores. Can anyone help me to find out why considering i am very new to programming. Thankyou :)

```
from random import shuffle
print ("Welcome to the quiz! ")
name = input('What is your name?: ')


with open ("questions.txt") as f:
    lines = f.readlines ()

shuffle (lines)
numRight = 0
wrong = []

numQuestions = int(input("How many questions? "))

for line in lines [:numQuestions]:
    question, rightAnswer = line.strip().split("\t")
    answer = input(question + '  ')
    rightAnswer = rightAnswer.lower()
    if answer.lower() == rightAnswer:
        print ("Right!")
        numRight +=1
    else:
        print ("No, the answer is", rightAnswer)
        wrong.append(question)


print ("You got %d right  " % (numRight))
if (wrong):
    print ("You got these wrong: ")
    for q in wrong:
        print (q)

user_class = input('What class are you in?: ').lower()
if user_class=="A":
    my_file = open("classAScores.txt")
    my_file.write(name + ' ' +str(numRight))
    my_file.close()

elif user_class =="B":
    my_file = open("classBScores.txt")
    my_file.write(name + ' ' + str(numRight))
    my_file.close()

elif user_class=="C":
    my_file = open("classCScores.txt")
    my_file.write(name + ' ' +str(numRight))
    my_file.close()
```

Comment: Why are you making your input lower case, then comparing against uppercase letters?

Comment: @StephenTG haha never thought of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this part of your code:

```
user_class = input('What class are you in?: ').lower()
if user_class=="a":
    with open("classAScores.txt",'a') as my_file:
        my_file.write(name + ' ' + str(numRight) + '\n')
```

Comment: Thankyou soooo much such i made such a stupid error!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about everything else from a first glance, however I can see one logical error for sure:

```
user_class = input('What class are you in?: ').lower()
if user_class=="A":
```

You apply `.lower()` to the string, then check for an uppercase "A", which will never occur.